# Flink Joins on Non-key attribute

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have a use-case in which I want to join on a key to non-key attribute on two datastreams in flink.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Please provide more detail, including an explanation of what you mean by "non-key attribute". Are you using the Table/SQL API, and want to join on an attribute that isn't annotated with "PRIMARY KEY", or are you using the DataStream API and want to join without doing a `keyBy`, or something else, perhaps?

Comment: 1) I want something like secondray index.

Comment: 2) If I am using dataStrram API then is it feasible to do joins without keyby()??

Comment: No, it's not possible to do a join without a keyBy().

Comment: Please provide a concrete example of what you are trying to do, preferably with code. But perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295777/how-to-support-multiple-keyby-in-flink will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. But you need to provide more context. Have you encountered the problem using a temporal `JOIN` with a `FOR SYSTEM TIME AS OF`?

This type of join requires a primary key to be declared. You can either use one that has been declared in a source (`PRIMARY KEY (..) NOT ENFORCED` with kafka-upsert for example). Or you can create one implicitly with [deduplication](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sql/queries.html#deduplication):

```
SELECT [column_list]
FROM (
   SELECT [column_list],
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER ([PARTITION BY col1[, col2...]]
       ORDER BY time_attr [asc|desc]) AS rownum
   FROM table_name)
WHERE rownum = 1
```